# Timing a single block in Jupyter with one line of code

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook

How do you time a single block of a Jupyter notebook with a single line of. Python code?

%time and %timeit don't cut it, but there must be a way to do this!

```
%time
%timeit
start = time.time()

## Create a Pandas dataframe from reader
df = pd.DataFrame(reader.readrows())
end = time.time()
print('Time taken ', end-start,' seconds')
```

Thanks, Nic

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. _Why_ don't `timeit` and `time` work? What exactly are you trying to do? You need to provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: `%time
%timeit`
start = time.time()

## Create a Pandas dataframe from reader
df = pd.DataFrame(reader.readrows())
end = time.time()
print('Time taken ', end-start,' seconds')

Comment: The code above seems awfully long winded!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the cell magic `%%timeit` (with two %) to time a whole jupyter cell, instead of just a single line. The cell magic must come before any python code in the cell.

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit

Comment: Nope, I just get a syntax error::File "<ipython-input-7-ed00422a9f6b>", line 2
    %%timeit
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Cell magics must be on the first line of the cell, or you will get that error.

Answer (score 5):

In Jupyter Notebook, we have a magic function `timeit` to time a whole cell.

```
%%timeit -n 10

#your code
```

Where 10 is the number of execution cycles.